# ClickHouse replica out of sync

Tags: database, database-replication, clickhouse

I have a cluster of 3 ClickHouse servers with a table using ReplicatedMergeTree. Two of the servers are out of sync and the count of queue in 'system.replication_queue' keeps increasing. I can see this error in logs.

```
Not executing log entry for part e87a3a2d13950a90846a513f435c2560_2428139_2436934_22 because source parts size (470.12 MiB) is greater than the current maximum (4.45 MiB).
```

How do I increase the source parts size? I could not find it in settings.

**Update:**

I read the source code, it is auto calculated based on the available resources. I am also getting this message

```
Not executing log entry for part de77ce6a2937ce543cd003eb289fdb7e_8097652_8107495_1904 because another log entry for the same part is being processed. This shouldn't happen often.
```

The servers which are getting the above message in log have high CPU usage and latency in inserts.

Replication Queue gets cleared once I stop insertion.

Comment: look at this one [github CH issue #10506](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/10506)

Comment: The article suggests that the issue is "merges are processing significantly slower than inserts" but I don't get that error in logs. I am sending only one request for addition per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It happens because of "merges are processing significantly slower than inserts" as suggested by @vladimir

I was inserting data in big batches but that does not mean that clickhouse will also store data in on big file. Clickhouse stores data based on

```
number of partitions * number of columns * (times 2 for every nullable column)
```

So even for insertion with a single large batch multiple files are created. I solved this issue by reducing the number of partitions by removing a partition key thereby reducing the number of files being created.

Comment: How can you tell this? Do you have any way to tell if this is the case? Anything in the logs?
 I'm seeing pretty big mismatch behaviour in daily-partitioned data from less than two-months data. In a small table, if one replica has 7000 entries, the other replica has around 6000. Looks like too much.